# This MoPub giving me headache

Tags: android, mopub, adcolony, mobile-ad-mediation

Anyone have any idea how to serve `Adcolony` ads via `MoPub` mediation?
Only this `MoPub` knows what kind of documentation they have posted in their developers section.

Information are here and there along with depreciated guidelines.

`MoPubRewardedVideos.loadRewardedVideo("YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID");`

They didn't say what Ad unit ID is this. If it's their own unit ID then where to find it.

---

Adding this: `MoPubRewardedVideos.initializeRewardedVideo(this);`

Producing error: 
`initializeRewardedVideo(android.app.Activity, com.mopub.common.MediationSettings...)' has private access in 'com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubRewardedVideos`

In Initialization tab it says: `MoPub.initializeSdk()`

Messed up everything

Answer (score 1):

In the 5.0.0 release, the SDK uses a new initialization API that will also initialize your rewarded video settings. If you have been using `MoPubRewardedVideos.initializeRewardedVideo()`, it is now part of the new initialization, so make sure to switch to the new API. Here's how to use the new API:

```
SdkConfiguration sdkConfiguration = new SdkConfiguration.Builder("AD_UNIT_ID")
                                                    .withMediationSettings("MEDIATION_SETTINGS")
                                                    .withNetworksToInit(networksToInit)
                                                    .build();

MoPub.initializeSdk(this, sdkConfiguration, initSdkListener());
```

The `AD_UNIT_ID` string is a placeholder for where our own ad unit ID should go. If you want a sample ad unit ID for testing purposes, you can check out these: https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/blob/bd1646fdce1a808b2ae39c41d6904db493214e4a/mopub-sample/res/values/strings.xml#L23-L29.